# Can't stop effect of C shortcut in Grease Pencil's draw mode

Tags: shortcut, draw-mode

Like the title says, I have created a new Grease Pencil Object (GPencil), went into the Draw Mode (upper left menu), than pressed <kbd>C</kbd>, but I can't exit from this feature (pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or anything else doesn't seem to help).

To be precise: pressing <kbd>C</kbd> in draw mode constrains the drawing into a circular/radial guide.

Possibly a bug?
Thanks
G

EDIT SOLUTION: Check the box in the upper viewport, with other guides checkboxes (Circular, Radial, Parallel...)

[image: solved]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. In draw mode <kbd>C</kbd> activates the circular guide. You can click on the guides icon to deactivate.

[image]